# Compile error saying "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Tags: vba, excel, compilation, basic

I have code that populates cells when double clicked on the cell. Here it is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)  
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C10:C19", "D10:D19", "E10:E19")) Is Nothing Then  
        Cancel = True  
        Target.Formula = Date  
    End If  
End Sub
```

The code was working fine until I added `"E10:E19"` then it gives me a compile error saying `wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignments` and then it highlights the first line of code `Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)`

Full disclosure: I am a total noob at this so any fixes or advice please explain like I am 5 years old.

Comment: you probably want `Range("C10:C19, D10:D19, E10:E19")` which is same as `Range("C10:E19")`

Comment: the `range` object expects one or two _arguments_ (input values). you had three.

Comment: one way to learn which cells a range object covers, is to use the _immediate window_  .... in VBE editor press ctrl-G and it should show up .... now resize the VBE editor so that you can see the worksheet and the immediate window .... then type into immediate window `range("b3").select` and press enter ... you should see cell B3 selected .... try others ... `range("b5:d7").select` ... `range("b5:d7, a1:a3, a6").select`  ... `range("b5:d7, a1:a3, a6").Offset(1).select
` ... `range("b5:d7, a1:a3, a6").Offset(2,3).select`  and so on

Comment: you can double-click the titlebar of the immediate window (where it says "immediate") and it will detach from the VBA editor. doubleclick again to reattach

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, helped clarify things very easily!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Try this*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, [C10:C19, D10:D19, E10:E19]) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Formula = Date
    End If
End Sub
```

*`"C10:C19", "D10:D19", "E10:E19"` Range should be one string not multiple strings* 
 *Examnple* `"C10:C19, D10:D19, E10:E19"`